# Best way to bind an interface to the result of another binding

Tags: c#, ninject

Let's say I have the following interface and class:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class MagicInterfaceImplementor<T>
{
    public T GetImplementation()
    {
        // Not relevant.
    }
}
```

The only way to get an instance of `IMyService` is through `MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>`.  I can obviously setup injection pretty easily for `MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>`:

```
Bind<MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>().ToSelf();
```

[Strictly, this isn't necessary in this particular instance, but I'm doing a bit more with the binding in the actual case.]

My question is - how do I bind `IMyService`?

I think I can do this, but I'm not sure that it's the best way, since I'm explicitly calling the Kernel, which is typically frowned upon:

```
Bind<IMyService>().ToMethod(context => {
    return ((MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>)
            context.Kernel.GetService(typeof(MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>)))
                .GetImplementation();
});
```

Any suggestions of a more proper way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does ninject support lambda resolution? Is it does, you might try the Ninject equivalent of 'Register<IMyService>(() => new MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>().GetImplementation()).AsSingleton()` or the lifecycle model of your choosing.

Comment: @Alex:  In the full case, I am actually doing the binding for the Magic class in order to assign a constructor parameter.  If I use `new`, I need to provide the parameter twice.  (Which is fine, since they're both in the same place and will be obvious when any changes are made - I was just hoping to be able to reuse what has already been setup.)

Comment: well maybe it supports a lambda that gets the container/resolver supplied as an agrment, as in: Register<IMyService>((container) =>  container.Resolve<MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>>().GetImplementation()).AsSingleton()`

Comment: @Alex:  That's basically what I have in the example. :)

Comment: Lol at the incomprehensible Ninject syntax for something so simple. Not really a lamda though with the `typeof` in there.

Comment: @Alex:  I'm not at my work laptop, but I could probably have done it more like yours (`context.Kernel.Resolve<>`), I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be interesting what exactly MagicImplementor does. So this is more of a guess, but maybe a Provider might help you.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context

Otherwise you can simply write

```
Bind<IMyService>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<MagicInterfaceImplementor<IMyService>>().GetImplementation());
```

Comment: I don't seem to have the .Get<T> method.

Comment: It's an extension method. Maybe that's why you don't see it.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a lot cleaner.  And, since there don't seem to be any better answers, I'll happily take a cleaner one.